# How should i use getDC as a local object with autocleanup ? c++

Tags: c++, gdi

I am new in c++, learning best ways of how to's.
I saw a lot of usefull examples on painting stuff, but i didn't saw any simple pimple getdc with smart class.

So i have written my own one:

```
class DCObject 
{
public:
    DCObject(HWND handle)
    {
        my_handle = handle;
        my_hdc = GetDC(my_handle);
    }

    HDC GetHDC() {
        return my_hdc;
    }

    ~DCObject()
    {
        ReleaseDC(my_handle, my_hdc);
    }
private:
    HWND my_handle;
    HDC my_hdc;
};
```

And i tryed to get hdc like this:

```
HDC mydc = DCObject(dialog_item_handle).GetHDC();
```

is this correct ? To asq for class method, firstly not creating a class object ? What happens with a class in this case ? maybe i do get the hdc and it instantly gets released ?(it works but it may produce undefined behaviour with hdc's ?)

Maybe i should do it like this:

```
DCObject myhdcobj(dialog_item_handle);
 HDC mydc = myhdcobj.GetHDC();
```

Comment: Do you use MFC? Check out the CDC (plus derived) class then!

Comment: oh no, i know about cdc(just red), i am not using mfc, didn't learned it yet. simple pimple win32 for now.

Comment: One important improvement to your class: disable copying (delete and/or make private the copy constructor and copy assignment operator), and do support moving (define a move constructor).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i think understood what you offered, still i am not quite sure how to do that. An example would be good if you can.

Comment: @Amas: OK, I just posted that as a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
HDC mydc = DCObject(dialog_item_handle).GetHDC();
```

invokes the `DCObject` constructor, creating a temporary object. A temporary object is (guaranteed) destroyed at the end of the full-expression. So after this statement the temporary object has been destroyed, and it destructor has called `ReleaseDC`…

Solution: store the object instead of the handle,

```
const DCObject mydc( dialog_item_handle );
```

---

I would prefer to write that as

```
auto const mydc = DCObject( dialog_item_handle );
```

… but with the `DCObject` class as presented in the question this is *not safe*, because there's no handling of copying/moving so the destructor of the temporary object on the right, will call `ReleaseDC`…

---

To enable the more natural `auto` notation for a constant declaration, and in general to enable moving and disable copying, do this:

```
class DCObject 
{
private:
    HWND my_handle;
    HDC my_hdc;

    DCObject( DCObject const& ) = delete;
    DCObject& operator=( DCObject const& ) = delete;

public:
    auto handle() const -> HDC { return my_hdc; }

    ~DCObject()
    { ReleaseDC( my_handle, my_hdc ); }

    DCObject( const HWND handle )
        : my_handle( handle )
        , my_hdc( GetDC( handle ) )
    {}

    DCObject( DCObject&& other )
        : my_handle( other.my_handle )
        , my_hdc( other.my_hdc )
    { other.my_hdc = 0; }
};
```

The code for other kinds of handles – even for other *uses* of device context handles – will be very similar.

And one main insight needed for expressing that as a general class template is that the additional state necessary for cleanup, e.g. here the window handle, can be part of a specified cleanup function or function-like object, in particular as captures in a lambda.

If you're not yet using lambdas then just keep that in mind.

You can use the principle of stateful deleter also without using lambdas.

Comment: This sounds right, but at first glampse i am not quite sure what are     DCObject( DCObject const& ) = delete;
    DCObject& operator=( DCObject const& ) = delete; for, could you explain ? and why auto is more natural ? isn't saying to compiler HDC faster, instead of declaring what we will return and using auto's ?

Comment: "= delete" is a C++11 feature. You can just omit that, use ordinary declarations (without function bodies). As far as the compiler is concerned it's mostly the same, it will anyway have to diagnose any attempt at copying, but the "= delete" communicates to the reader of the code that these functions are intentionally not implemented.

Comment: Thanks, i am jumping ahead of myself a bit. I should read more tutorials. I was just looking at RAII with simple new allocations, maybe you can point me to some usefull tutorials about that(RAII) or give me new allocation example ? i am allocating a float array

Comment: 44 mins of research, this is how far i got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629781/c-new-c-array-allocation-raii-or-simple-shared-ptr-boostshared-array

Comment: @Arnas: Oh just use `std::vector`. The only improvement with a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is that you can avoid zeroing the memory initially, for the case where it's filled in by some API function. But usually it's not worth it.

Comment: And that is my case ! it is filled by other function and it is created/deleted at a 100Hz rate so it is not worth filling it uselessly :) Still this is a learning process and i am happy about any new thingies i do learn. So thanks for your help, you did answered a lot of my stupid questions, i am getting better bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <windows.h>

template<typename T, typename D = void(*)(T &val)>
struct gdi_type
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type type;
    typedef typename std::unique_ptr<typename gdi_type<T>::type, D> unique_ptr_type;
};

template<typename T>
auto safe_gdi(const T &val)
{
    return typename gdi_type<T>::unique_ptr_type(val, [](T &t) {DeleteObject(t);});
}

auto safe_gdi(const HDC &val)
{
    return gdi_type<HDC>::unique_ptr_type(val, [](HDC &t) {DeleteDC(t);});
}

auto safe_gdi(const HWND &win, const HDC &val)
{
    auto deleter = [=](HDC &val) {ReleaseDC(win, val); val = nullptr;};
    return gdi_type<HDC, decltype(deleter)>::unique_ptr_type(val, deleter);
}

int main()
{
    HWND win = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC DC = safe_gdi(win, GetDC(win)).get();

    HDC CDC = safe_gdi(CreateCompatibleDC(DC)).get();

    HPEN PEN = safe_gdi(CreatePen(PS_DASH, 0, 0xFF)).get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm, this is quantum physics for me for now. At first glimpse this looks smarter since(i am guessin) it uses the approperiate cleaning  function for each type of gdi handles or whatever ?, cleans it when variable is released. Still i have never ever used any of these smart pointers in my life till now. I dont think ill jump straight into those ^^ I will try them later

Comment: Thats interesting style. You do not assing the temporary unique_ptr objects to anything. You just assing their content. Can you be shure they are not handled like rValues and get prematurely destroyed. I mean the compiler may decide they are not used anymore and destroy them just next line. Is there some language definition that guarantees that they live to the closing braket?

Comment: Ah you're right, you have to keep them around. They are indeed destroyed on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign `DCObject(dialog_item_handle)` to a variable, you end up with a [Temporary Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8kfxa78.aspx).

Temporary objects are destroyed when the expression that creates them is done. In your case, right after the assignment to `mydc`. So right after `mydc` is assigned, the temporary object's destructor will be called, and the DC will be released. Not what you want.

The second version will work. Your `myhdcobj` will only be destroyed when it goes out of scope - that is, when you leave the function.

Comment: Just what i tought, just wanted to clarify it and leave this question open for the world. Maybe more noobs like me will have less problems with gdi in the future. 
Could do it somehow smarter or is everything fine here ?