# c++ new C array allocation, RAII or simple shared_ptr / boost::shared_array

Tags: c++, raii

I am learning c++ and i stumbled once again on a new issue.

I do need to allocate a C array for a library to use, but in a safe way, ofcourse. I already found that delete[]; at the end of method fails miserably.

OLD, not that good:

```
float *buf;

try {
    buf = new float[daswidth*chans_info.chans*sizeof(float)];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) // sometimes it throws ! so i do need to stop my execution.
{
    if (DEBUG) tekstasFormat(L"WARNING: bad alloc caught: %s", ba.what());
    return; // skip this iteration then.
}

//... OUR CODE

delete[] buf;
```

So what i tryed to use which works perfectly instead of my old allocation and deletion:

```
float *buf;

std::shared_ptr<float> safe_buf(new float[daswidth*chans_info.chans*sizeof(float)], [](float *p) { delete[] p; });

// OR BOOST EQUIVALENT
boost::shared_array<float> safe_buf(new float[daswidth*chans_info.chans*sizeof(float)]);

buf = safe_buf.get();
```

And we do never leak, everyone is happy.
But how to catch new_alloc throws now ?!

if i will allocate shared_ptr in a new{} scope after new it gets destroyed... Explain me and noobs like me for the future a bit more. 
How to handle exceptions in this case ?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant use `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::vector` actually contains an `T*` that is created when you initialize it. There will be some small overhead with the checks and functions called when using it but its definitely worth it.

Comment: That `sizeof(float)` seems suspicious here. Don't know what is your use case, but `new float[n*sizeof(float)]` allocates `n*sizeof(float)` floats, not `n*sizeof(float)` bytes. Just so you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer `std::unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`.  It's far faster.

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> buf; //construct

try {
    buf.reset(new float[daswidth*chans_info.chans*sizeof(float)]); //give memory
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) // sometimes it throws ! so i do need to stop my execution.
{
    if (DEBUG) tekstasFormat(L"WARNING: bad alloc caught: %s", ba.what());
    return; // skip this iteration then.
}
```

However, as `Ben` said, there's pretty much no reason to use a `float[]` like this.  Instead, use `std::vector`.  Yes, even for most* C interop.

```
std::vector<float> buf;

try {
    buf.resize(daswidth*chans_info.chans*sizeof(float)); //give memory
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) // sometimes it throws ! so i do need to stop my execution.
{
    if (DEBUG) tekstasFormat(L"WARNING: bad alloc caught: %s", ba.what());
    return; // skip this iteration then.
}

function_expecting_float_pointer(buf.data()); //use .data() to get the `float*`
```

*don't use `std::vector` if the C code will ever "reallocate" the pointer for you.  Instead, use `std::unique_ptr`, and (1) release the memory, (2) pass to C, (3) reset with pointer returned from C.

Comment: Thanks duck, .reset is what i needed. Resetting the size of ptr when allocating new data is the way to go which i didnt knew about. But, one question - isnt c array faster than vector within same usage as c array ?

Comment: @Arnas: Only in one very specific way: C arrays don't initialize data by default, and `vector` will try to initialize it's elements by default.  Correct and careful use of `vector` will make them the same speed, but if you don't know what you're doing, it can theoretically sometimes be ever so slightly slower.  However, it's always significantly easier and safer.  Use it.  Always.

Comment: Well, in my case i would prefer unique_ptr then, since it would initialize whole array at a 100Hz rate which is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Arnas: (1) There's few reasons you need code to run at 100Hz.  Usually 60Hz is more of a max.  (2) The only time it would be unnecessary is if the C code is initializing the array for you.  Is that the case?